# Choosing Object in For Loop based on Input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to populate select options based on the value of the previously selected option.

```
            <label for="state" class="block">State:*</label>
            <select name="state" id="state" tabindex="1">
                <option value="Arizona">Arizona</option>
                <option value="Arkansas">Arkansas</option>
                <option value="Colorado">Colorado</option>
            </select>

            <label for="location" class="block">Preferred Location:*</label>
            <select name="location" id="location" tabindex="2">
                <option value=""></option>
            </select>
```

Thats my html. Right now I have my js, and it works, but I'm wondering if there is a petter way.

```
        var State = $('#state').val();
        var Location = $('#location');



        setOptions(State);

        function setOptions(chosen){

        var Location=document.myform.location;
        Location.options.length=0;

        var Arizona = {
        0 : 'Select Location',
        3 : 'Phoenix (Chandler)',
        4 : 'Scottsdale',
        5 : 'Tuscon'
        };

        var Arkansas = {
        2 : 'Little Rock'
        };          

        var Colorado = {
        6 : 'Colorado Springs'
        };




        if(chosen=="Arizona"){              
        var myobject = Arizona;
        }

        if(chosen=="Arkansas"){
        var myobject = Arkansas;
        }

        if(chosen=="Colorado"){         
        var myobject = Colorado;
        }

        for(index in myobject) {
                Location.options[Location.options.length]=new Option(myobject[index], index);
        }
```

Is there a way I can tell it which object to use based on the other select box?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use nested objects:

```
var locations = {
    Arizona: {
        0 : 'Select Location',
        3 : 'Phoenix (Chandler)',
        4 : 'Scottsdale',
        5 : 'Tuscon'
    },
    Arkansas: {
        2 : 'Little Rock'
    },
    Colorado: {
        6 : 'Colorado Springs'
    }
};

var myobject = locations[chosen];
for(index in myobject) {
    Location.options.push(new Option(myobject[index], index));
}
```

Comment: say rather than create select options, I wanted to create an un ordered list. Would that be possible?

Comment: Sure. The way you organize your data has nothing to do with what you do with the values.

Comment: Would you mind showing me how? I'm very beginner. I'd like to rather than put out a select option create something like <li data-value="the numeric value">location name</li>

Comment: I suggest you read your Javascript texts to learn how to add elements to the DOM. Then try it on your own, and if you have a problem post a new question. I mainly use jQuery for this type of stuff, I can't quickly compose an answer in plain Javascript.